# OpenGL - Texturing, unwanted skewing and rotating

Tags: opengl, texturing

I'm trying to map several texture atlases onto various quads on a car object. I am coming across a problem where some textures are skewed and rotated rather than mapping directly onto a quad. The problem is shown below, I've used a smiley face for a clearer example of what's going on. [image: Skewed/rotated Image]

I've tried to make the texture atlases' widths powers of 2, that does not work. I also heard from a friend that this is due to the texture atlases not being an even width, which didn't resolve the problem for all cases. The fact that changing the width managed to solve the problem in some cases leads me to believe that texture width may be the cause.

I'm using my own shaders to perform texture co-ordinate manipulation for the texture atlases, if this is relevant. Does anyody have any clues as to the cause of this problem?

Comment: "Does anyody have any clues as to the cause of this problem?" Not really, since you haven't shown us so much as a line of code. You need to actually give us something here, not just a description of what you want to happen. You have a bug in your code; we can't do anything about that unless you show us that code.

Comment: Looks like texture coordinate problem, but without any code, we can't tell.

Comment: It's not having a width that isn't a power-of-2 that causes this, it's a mismatch between the actual width (in the memory layout, e.g. Windows bitmaps are always a multiple of 4 bytes per scanline) vs the width you told OpenGL the texture has.

Comment: Sorry about that, I couldn't really post code without the question being over-cluttered. There are many parts of the code that could have been at fault, so I just wanted to see if this type of problem rang any bells for anybody. I wasn't really looking for a complete solution, rather a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your left image I see some out-of-place black pixels. That kind of things happen when you load image wrongly (part of images header goes to RGBA data).

Another possible reason is wrong width of image in header and in data (could caused by wrongful header usage or padding in images data).

Without code and image format it's harder to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks this has given me some ideas, I will look and see if these are the causes. I'll update this question with more detail and a solution when I find it.

Comment: If your update is going to shift focus from initial question please make a new one :)